# Is it on-topic to ask about identification of a specific equipment shown in a picture?

Tags: discussion, scope

is it on-topic to ask for the identification of a specific equipment shown in a picture? 
In my case I've a model wearing a motorbike helmet. I would like to know which exact product he's wearing. 
Per definition it's off-topic but I guess that motorbike-equipment generally still can be discussed here, can't it? However, still disputable whether identification of a specific piece is on-topic.

Thanks :)

Comment: That's an interesting subject. My gut check is it would still be on topic, but I'm only leaning this way. Would like to see what the rest of the community has to say. It isn't technically a *shopping* question and you aren't asking where to buy it at or how much it costs, just exactly the manufacture. It may be hard to answer and you might never get one, but it may be worth a try. Like I said, let's let others pipe in here.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Gave it a try: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/47312/22541

Comment: Regardless, I'm sure you'd have bettee response on some motorcycle forum

Comment: @agentp since the question is already answered it don't think so ;P